# can one use temp tables in teradata

Tags: sql-server, teradata

Is there an equivalent for this sql server tsql in teradata:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SomeTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SomeTempTable;

CREATE TABLE #SomeTempTable (Bla NVARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO #SomeTempTable
SELECT N'a'
    UNION ALL
SELECT N'B'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent for the 1st statement, there might be a Stored Procedure for it like this:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE Drop_Table_If_Exists
(
  IN db_name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET UNICODE,
  IN tbl_name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET UNICODE,
  OUT msg VARCHAR(400) CHARACTER SET UNICODE
) SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
   DECLARE full_name VARCHAR(361)  CHARACTER SET UNICODE;

   DECLARE sql_stmt VARCHAR(500)  CHARACTER SET UNICODE;
   DECLARE exit HANDLER FOR SQLCODE 'T3807'--SQLEXCEPTION
   BEGIN
      IF SQLCODE = 3807 THEN SET msg = full_name || ' doesn''t exist.';
      ELSE
        RESIGNAL;
      END if;
   END;

   SET full_name = '"' || COALESCE(db_name,DATABASE) || '"."' || tbl_name || '"';

   SET sql_stmt = 'DROP TABLE ' || full_name || ';';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;

   SET msg = full_name || ' dropped.';
END;
```

A `VOLATILE` table exists only within your current session (i.e. the same name might be used in different sessions for different tables) and is automatically dropped when the session disconnects. When you keep the naming convention (name of a temporary starts with `#`) you probably don't need the conditional Drop (you should know if you already created this table in the current session):

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE #SomeTempTable( 
Bla VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Caution, if you don't specify the Primary Index it will default to a NUPI on the first column.

The Select has a strange restriction, you need a `FROM` when you do a Set Operation like `UNION`/`INTERSECT`/`EXCEPT`. Workaround is either a dummy view (similar to Oracle's DUAL table) like this:

```
replace view dummy as select 1 as x;

INSERT INTO #SomeTempTable
SELECT 'a' FROM dummy
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' FROM dummy
```

or a similar CTE:

```
INSERT INTO #SomeTempTable
WITH dummy AS (select 1 as x)
SELECT 'a' FROM dummy
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' FROM dummy
```

Comment: Thanks. I played around with this but none of it works. is there really no way in teradata to test some sql code using some temp (volatile) table with some sample data? The check for the existence of #SomeTempTable is there so that the same script can be rerun.

Comment: @csetzkorn: *none of it works*, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @csetzkorn: I just fixed the SP source, it was a cut&paste from my history, didn't notice it was buggy.

Comment: Thanks. Do not seem to have the rights to REPLACE PROCEDURE.

Comment: @csetzkorn: Bad luck, a lot of Teradata DBAs only allow some highly trusted developers to create SPs (as it's the only place where you can do very inefficient things like cursors)